# Do both these structures create the same meaning: ".... would not have been able to do ...." VS ".... couldn't have done...."

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, modal-verbs

The following sentence is from a text about a new genetic testing method which reveals whether a tumor is cancerous or not, without having to apply chemotherapy. [BBC - Genetic testing spared baby unncessary chemotherapy](https://www.bbc.com/news/health-63093117)

**"We would not have been able to pick this up by any other test - genetic or otherwise,"** says Dr Behjati.

In this sentence, the structure **"....would not have been able to pick..."** is too wordy. And it seems that it is used to create a meaning which can also be created by another but shorter structure in the English language: **"...could not have picked .....".**

**"We couldn't have picked this up by any other test - genetic or otherwise,"** says Dr Behjati.

So, as a non-native speaker, both sentences seem to have the same meaning to me. Do they to you, native speakers?

Comment: ***In your opinion** the structure "....would not have been able to pick..." is too wordy.* I've no idea whether Dr Behjati is a native Anglophone or not, but I certainly wouldn't criticize his choice of phrasing. If pressed to distinguish the two, I'd say Dr Behjati's actual choice is slightly more emphatic, in that it tends towards *We would **never** have been able to pick this up...* But then again the other one could be "intensified" by *We couldn't **possibly** have picked this up...* Different people may prefer one version over the other for any number of reasons.